# How to input DateTime Now in ASP.NET MVC from the hidden form input to database MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to input datetime now to record add item time. I currently use an input form with a hidden type to insert datetime into the database table column but it fails. How do I input datetime now in realtime with the format yyyy-mm-dd hh: mm: ss time format 24 hours into the database?, for example 2019-10-23 16:30:49. I am using ASP.NET MVC with MySql Database. Thank You

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="CreateItem">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NameItem">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="AddTime" value="DateTimeNow">
</form>
```

Comment: If you call "CreateItem" method, can you add the AddTime in that method?

Comment: I agree with @Emanuele, why put the date in a text field while you can use `DateTime.Now` in C# or `getdate()` in mssql directly when the form is posted?

Comment: It is not advisable to add datetime from client side, you should add it using server side..  so assign `DateTime.Now` to object in backend before inserting record to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to add datetime from client side, you should add it using server side.. so assign DateTime.Now to object in backend before inserting record to database

why datetime should not be created using Client side?

Assume users trying to access application from different countries which have different time zone, then datetime will not be accurate in database, so when try to generate report or check anything based on datetime orders, then it will lead to confusion.

so the solution is to add datetime to class object before inserting to database as the following

```
 [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateMethod([FromBody] MyClass model)
  mode.CreationDate =  DateTime.Now;
  //then insert record to database
```